# How to display tabhost for activity witout using tabHost.addTab(spec) in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I used tab widget in my app.

I have ListActivity class for display listview items, but i don't want to add on tabhost using tabhost.addTab(spec).

I want to display tab widget on bottom in ListActivity. I also use `<include layout...>` for include whole layout on list.xml file.

But nothing to displayed.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: But your First Activity will be extends with `TabActivity` or `FragmentActivity`??

Comment: my first activity extends TabActivity not FragmentActivity.

Comment: Then call your Activity from it which is extends with ListActivity.

Comment: Actually i am not using ListActivity for displaying lisview items but i use activity.

Comment: I want to display tab widget on bottom side without adding activity on tab widget.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this library:[Iphone-Tab-in-Android](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android),you can get the demo [here](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html).

Comment: my question was how to display tab widget witjout using addTab(spec) in android. Because i have Activity class which display list item, now i want to display tab on bottom without using addTab(spec). Got it?